# get js checkbox label value in nsstring

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I have successfully created js checkbox in uiwebview by using this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //---------------- UITapGesture on UIWebView-----------------------
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detectTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.delegate = self;
    [self.webview addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"'Sudhaadagdudgdada'",@"'qwertyuiopo'",@"'asdfghjkl'", nil];
        NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div id='check'></div><script> var j; var jsArray = new Array %@; str=''; for(j = 0; j< 3;  j++){ str += '<label><input type=\"radio\" style=\"padding:25px;border-radius:35px;\" id=\"one_'+j+'\" name = \"Sudha\" value = \"'+jsArray[j]+'\" onclick=\"showvalue(this.value);\" />'+jsArray[j]+'</input><br/><br/>'; } document.getElementById(\"check\").innerHTML=str; </script>",array];
    NSLog(@"html..%@",html);

        [self.webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

}
```

Now I want to get checkbox onclick value in nsstring by UITapGeture on UIWebView.
I am trying this code but alert showing proper value but returns nothing :

```
#pragma mark Tap Gesture MEthod
- (void) detectTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    NSString *result = [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                        @"function showvalue(data)  {alert(data);return data;} showvalue(data) "]; //try 2
    NSLog(@"result..%@",result);

}
```

Please help me to get checkbox value in NSString.Is there any another way to get text from uiwebview where I have touched or anything else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you are bringing webview here? create your own checkbox style view and use it... [see here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tncheckboxgroup) & [here for all available controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=checkbox)

Comment: I am using uiwebview because all data is coming in HTML format from server. Thats why I am not using available controls

Comment: not sure, but I think what you are doing is wrong. What you can do is call a webservice to show the checkbox options... doing in webview is bad design...